# Strange IE form file select bug

Tags: forms, internet-explorer

I am making a simple image uploader. Since normal file selected cannot be styled do i use a bit of javascript to overcome this. There's just one problem, when someone using IE trys to upload a file by pressing the "fake" file select bar and press submit the selected image disappear. Do anyone know why this happens?

[Try it for yourself](http://hemb.priv.no/fileUploadBugIE.php)

File score (same as in link above):

```
<form action="fileUploadBugIE.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" character_set="UTF_8" > 

    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="filePath" onclick="document.getElementById('fileUL').click();" /><br /><br />
    <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="fileUL" onchange="document.getElementById('filePath').value = this.value;"/><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: because internet explorer sucks

Comment: ^^ my answer to >90% of IE-related questions